# gulp-sourcemaps generates an empty names property

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-sourcemaps, gulp-uglify

I'm trying to generate sourcemap files for uglified javascript with gulp. My task looks as follows:

```
gulp.task('scripts', ['clean'], function() {

  return gulp.src([ 'src/app/**/*.js' ])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/app'));

});
```

The output map generated by `gulp-sourcemaps` contains an empty `names` array, which prevents the browser to unmangle the function arguments back to its original names.

It seems to me that `gulp-sourcemaps` isn't merging the chained map files correctly? The `gulp-concat` does not output a `names` property (it doesn't needs to: it's simply concating) but `gulp-uglify` does:

```
gulp.task('scripts', ['clean'], function() {

  return gulp.src([ 'src/app/**/*.js' ])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
//    .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/app'));

});
```

The above does generates correct map files with the `names` property set.

Am I doing something wrong or does someone has a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in Uglify2. Should be resolved by this simple fix:

https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/pull/546